# Is it safe to run FreeNAS inside VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualization, nas

I was planning on running FreeNAS on Virtualbox, the OS on a separate vmdk disk, then creating and using another vmdk disk(s) for the actual storage.  This is for my home network (though I do have ALOT of files to be stored/served).  I just ran across an article stating that running a setup like this WILL at some point lead to data loss.  Is this true?  Is it that unsafe to run FreeNAS (not using ZFS) in vbox?  If so, would Xen or KVM be any better? (According to the same article, they would not be.)

I'll be running it on a Zotac (atom cpu) booksized computer, the computer itself with 16 GB or ram, a 1 TB internal drive and a 2 TB external usb drive.

Here is a link to that article:

- http://forums.freenas.org/threads/absolutely-must-virtualize-freenas-a-guide-to-not-completely-losing-your-data.12714/

Comment: Why do you want to run it on a virtual machine? Just wondering..

Comment: I want the ease of use of FreeNAS, but I also need to run at least 1 other vm as a web server, and a couple of vm's as devel environments.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be safe?  I wouldn't store anything vital on it as a single copy.

Comment: Actually, according to the article, using Xen would PROBABLY be better, and I believe using KVM would be better as well.  For a home NAS, you are probably OK - as long as you keep backups and are not worried about the performance hit, but why not just use your favorite linux distro in a VM and throw SAMBA on it ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with 100% certainty, but the poster doesn't appear to be officially linked to FreeNAS, as he is just a forum member.  Glancing over the article he posted, the concerns are legitimate, but focused more on enterprise level use than on home use.

You should not have any issues.